# MySQL: Return stats over grouped by date with subqueries

Tags: mysql

I'm returning some stats from a table (over a time period) with a couple of subqueries and group by a datetime (converted to date). Although the query works, it takes around 20 minutes to complete with a table with around 2million rows. There is already an index on the date column (which unfortunately is datetime). I suspect the slow hog in this particular case is my usage of the DATE() function to convert the datetimes to date first for comparison. Any suggestions on how I can speed this up a bit? One way I could do this is by adding another column to the database that saves the date value for each row when adding it but maybe there is something obvious I can do without having to duplicate the date when adding it the first time around:

```
 $sql = "
    SELECT
        (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `mg_logs` WHERE `mg_authtype_id`=1 AND `mg_mailbox_id`=? AND DATE(`date`)=DATE(`l`.`date`)) AS `count1`,
        (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `mg_logs` WHERE `mg_authtype_id`=2 AND `mg_mailbox_id`=? AND DATE(`date`)=DATE(`l`.`date`)) AS `count2`,
        (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `mg_logs` WHERE `mg_authtype_id`=3 AND `mg_mailbox_id`=? AND DATE(`date`)=DATE(`l`.`date`)) AS `count3`,
        (SELECT COUNT(`id`) FROM `mg_logs` WHERE `mg_authtype_id`=4 AND `mg_mailbox_id`=? AND DATE(`date`)=DATE(`l`.`date`)) AS `count4`,
        DATE(`l`.`date`) AS `sdate`
    FROM 
        `mg_logs` `l`
    WHERE 
        `l`.`mg_mailbox_id`=?
    GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
    ";
```

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will certainly help if you can add the date column. However, remove the subqueries should also help:

```
$sql = "
    SELECT
        SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`mg_authtype_id`=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count1`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`mg_authtype_id`=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count2`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`mg_authtype_id`=3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count3`,
        SUM(CASE WHEN `l`.`mg_authtype_id`=4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `count4`,
        DATE(`l`.`date`) AS `sdate`
    FROM 
        `mg_logs` `l`
    WHERE 
        `l`.`mg_mailbox_id`=?
    GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
    ";
```

Comment: Also, do you have index on mg_mailbox_id?

Comment: Thanks Peter, your answer worked but still opted for date column as it makes most sense. As your answer did infact provide a faster solution, I'll keep it as the answer :)